# trying to find a simplier way to do automatic reversal of .on and off. state in swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

```
myMenuItem.state = NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: Int(truncating: Bool(myMenuItem.state == .off) as NSNumber))
```

i've been using this line to turn off when its on and on when its off
a menu item using swift
is there a simplier way to do the same thing using the same state ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to toggle the state between on and off, you can simply do:

```
myMenuItem.state = myMenuItem.state == .off ? .on : .off
```

Alternatively, you can add an extension on `NSControl.StateValue`:

```
extension NSControl.StateValue {
    mutating func toggle() {
        if self == .off {
            self = .on
        } else {
            self = .off
        }
    }
}

// usage:
myMenuItem.state.toggle()
```

Comment: thx for your nswer, can you explain the meaning of ".off ? .on : .off"

Comment: @papi_douchy that’s the ternary operator. `x ? a : b` evaluates to `a` if `x` is true, otherwise it evaluates to `b`.